# Want to count the number of text skipping first block using python or pandas

Tags: python, pandas

```
 dataframe                        col1
 index0   '......kkkkkkk......kkkkkkkkk.....kkkkkkkkkkkk'
 index1   '......kkkkkkkkk.........kkkkkkk.......kkkkkkkk...

     
  result        1st block of'k'       2nd block of '.'
 index0             7                         6
 index1             9                         9
```

here are text, but i want to count the number of 1st block of 'k' = 7, and the number of 2nd block of '.' = 6.@ index0
and 9 and 9 for index1

Comment: 1- there is no `'1'`, 2-, how is the related to [tag:pandas]? Please provide an explicit input

Comment: Please explain carefully what it is you want to do.  It isn't clear.  Please also include your code.

Comment: Oops... Really Sorry. I will fix my question..

Comment: Thanks for you edit, but what is the link with pandas?

Comment: Actually, doesn't need to using pandas. it will be okay using anyother python code. :)

Comment: Make sure your questions are clear and don't change all the time. Anyway I provided an answer both in python and pandas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

##### updated question (python only)

You can use a simple list comprehension and [`re.finditer`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.finditer):

```
import re

a = 'ooooooookkkkkkkoooookkkkkkkkkooooooooookkkkkkkkkkkk'

out = [len(m.group()) for m in re.finditer(r'k+', a)]
```

Or with [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
from itertools import groupby

out = [len(list(g)) for k, g in groupby(a, key=lambda x: x == 'k') if k]
```

Output:

```
[7, 9, 12]
```

##### original question (pandas)

Assuming such an input:

```
                                                         col
0   ......kkkkkkk.........kkkkkkkkk.............kkkkkkkkkkkk
1      ......kkk..kkkk............kkkkkkkkk.........kkkkkkkk
```

You could use [`extractall`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extractall.html) and [`str.len`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.len.html), then optionally [`unstack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html):

```
df['col'].str.extractall('(k+)')[0].str.len().unstack('match', fill_value=0)
```

Output:

```
match  0  1   2  3
0      7  9  12  0
1      3  4   9  8
```

Alternatively:

```
import re
df['sizes'] = [[len(m.group()) for m in re.finditer(r'k+', s)]
               for s in df['col']]
```

Output:

```
                                                 col         sizes
0   ......kkkkkkk.........kkkkkkkkk.............k...    [7, 9, 12]
1   ......kkk..kkkk............kkkkkkkkk............  [3, 4, 9, 8]
```

Comment: Really sorry for all the visitor, I'm begginer of Python World. And Take your all the comment in my heart. Thx for my poor Question...

Comment: No worries, we've all been beginners, I hope this helped.